# Sums of vector space and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In many questions, I see that we have that given $X,Y$ as subspaces of $R^n$ then $V=\{ x+y \mid x \in X, y \in Y\}$ is a subspace. I understand the proof of this. I am not sure why the subtlety that the dimension of $X,Y$ being the same is left out. Maybe it's something trivial I am missing. For example take one subspace as the $x$ axis and the other as the 2D plane then how do I define the sum? 
So the question is, do we need that for the definition of $V$, the dimensions of $X,$ be the same?

Comment: No, the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$ do not have to be the same. The sum is defined using the addition operation on $\mathbb R^n$, why would this require that $\dim X = \dim Y$?

Comment: How do I add a point in 2D such as (1,0) and in 1D such as (1), both of which belong to different dimension subspaces? What is the addition operation in this case?

Comment: Why are you trying to add something from $\mathbb R$ to something from $\mathbb R^2$? $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces of the _same_ $\mathbb R^n$ in your question.

Comment: @bissi the "length" of the vectors is not the dimension of the subspaces $X$ or $Y$. As they are subspaces of a common vector space $\mathbb R^n$, the addition is well-defined (and the vectors have the same length). By "length" I meant the number of the components, not the norm.

Comment: @bissi when  we say $\mathbb{R}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we mean that every real number can be seen as a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ for example : $t\in \mathbb{R}$ can be seen as $(t,0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @Hamza so in my comment should I look at adding (1,0) and (1,0) ?

Comment: @user251257 I see. Could you give an example of a subspace formed by addition when length of components are not the same? Preferably a simple one..

Comment: @SantiagoCanez the last comment was for you as well

Comment: No, you cannot add vectors which do not have the same number of components.  You're not using the term "dimension" correctly: it does not refer to the number of components, but rather to the size of a basis. For instance, in $\mathbb R^3$, the $x$-axis has dimension $1$ and the $yz$-plane has dimension $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused as to how to define a subspace formed by the addition of subspaces of different number of basis vectors.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Does the addition hold only if the subspaces are defined on the same space, in your case $R^3$?

Comment: Yes, it only makes sense to add subspaces of the same space.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Got it, then it all makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give an official answer, and to summarize some of the confusion brought up in the comments:

The sum of subspaces is only defined for subspaces of the *same* vector space. So, it wouldn't make sense to take the sum of $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ for instance. If $X$ and $Y$ are both subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$, so both consist of vectors with $n$ components, then adding an element of $X$ to an element of $Y$ makes perfect sense.

For instance, take $X$ to be the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ consisting of all vectors of the form $(x,0,0)$ and $Y$ to be the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ consisting of all vectors of the form $(0,y,z)$. Then $X+Y$ consists of all vectors of the form

$$(x,0,0) + (0,y,z) = (x,y,z),$$

meaning that $X+Y$ is all of $\mathbb R^3$. In this case, $X$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace and $Y$ a $2$-dimensional subspace, where "dimension" refers to the linear-algebraic notion of dimension (i.e. the number of vectors in a basis), and does *not* refer to the number of components an element of $X$ or $Y$ has.